# Improving query run time (Takes more than 20seconds to load a page)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've got a query which is loaded everytime the user open his profile page.
and its really slow. it takes more than 20 seconds to load the page.
its kinda simple query, but with alot of lines so don't be scared looking at it. :)

I would appericiate any help on improving my query.

```
SELECT 
    `h`.`login` AS `login`,
    SUM(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `total_pips`,
    COUNT(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`position_num`,NULL)) AS `total_trades`,
    (COUNT(IF(((`h`.`pl` > 0) AND ((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1))),`h`.`pl`,NULL)) / COUNT(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`position_num`,NULL))) AS `winning_trades_percent`,
    SUM(if(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`gain`,NULL)) AS `total_gain`,
    (SELECT AVG(`wg`.`weekly_gain_all`) FROM `gt_view_weekly_gain` `wg` where (`wg`.`login` = `h`.`login`) group by `wg`.`login`) AS `weekly_gain`,
    AVG(IF(((`h`.`pips` > 0) AND ((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1))),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `average_profit_pips`,
    AVG(IF(((`h`.`pips` <= 0) AND ((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1))),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `average_lose_pips`,
    AVG(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `average_pips`,
    AVG(time_to_sec(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),timediff(`h`.`close_time`,`h`.`open_time`),NULL))) AS `average_trade_time`,
    STD(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `volatility`,
    MAX(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `best_trade`,
    MIN(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) AS `worst_trade`,
    (ceiling(((ceiling(to_days(now())) - ceiling(to_days(MIN(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`open_time`,NULL))))) / 7)) - 1) AS `running_weeks`,
    (SELECT `fn`.`followers_num_all` FROM `gt_view_followers_num` `fn` where ((`fn`.`guru_id` = `h`.`guru_or_guru_user_id`) AND (`h`.`is_guru_history` = 1))) AS `followers_num`,
    SUM(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)),`h`.`pl`,NULL)) AS `total_profit_loss`,
    SUM(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 6) AND (`h`.`pl` > 0)),`h`.`pl`,NULL)) AS `deposits`,
    SUM(IF(((`h`.`cmd` = 6) AND (`h`.`pl` < 0)),`h`.`pl`,NULL)) AS `withdrawls`,
    COUNT(IF((((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)) AND (`h`.`pl` > 0)),`h`.`position_num`,NULL)) AS `total_winning_trades_count`,
    ABS((AVG(IF(((`h`.`pips` > 0) AND ((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1))),`h`.`pips`,NULL)) / AVG(IF(((`h`.`pips` <= 0) AND ((`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1))),`h`.`pips`,NULL)))) AS `average_profit_loss_ratio` 
FROM 
    `gt_history` `h` 
WHERE
    `h`.`is_closed` = 1
GROUP BY
    `h`.`login`
```

Comment: This query is unreadable, why don't you cache the response and only refresh cache if user changes something or once a day ?

Comment: Thank you for your'e response :). I've made it a readable as possible every line represents a row. and its a simple sum/if/count. I think the problems comes from the select statements. any idea how I could improve it?

Comment: Can you please what tables (supply dataschema) you have and what you want to do? I think that would make it easier to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this query computes the values for all the users. If you wish to display this for only one user, then it might be much faster to add `and (login='xxx')` in the where clause.

Otherwise, as Mihai suggested, caching might be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! :) it improved the query from 20 sec to 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "(`h`.`cmd` = 0) OR (`h`.`cmd` = 1)" in every columns IF, try filtering it in where clause. It might improve, since data selection is reduced.

Comment: How would you suggest to do it?

Comment: You are suppressing all other values of h.cmd with NULL. You only consider (h.cmd = 0) OR (h.cmd = 1). So its better if you use it in where clause "WHERE `h`.`is_closed` = 1 and ((h.cmd = 0) OR (h.cmd = 1))".